# Scala: compile error with wildcards (type parameters) and collections: "you may wish to investigate a wildcard type as"

Tags: scala, generics, type-conversion, covariance, type-parameter

Say I have a class named `Box` with a type parameter, and it has the following utility methods:

```scala
class Box[T]

object Box {
    def build() : Box[_] = ???
    def combine(boxes: Set[Box[_]]) : Unit = ???
}
```

I'm trying to use these methods in several ways. Some will compile, some will not:

```scala
// 1
Box.combine(Set(Box.build())) // compiles

// 2
val boxes : Set[Box[_]] = Set(Box.build())
Box.combine(boxes) // compiles

// 3
val boxes2 = Set(Box.build())
Box.combine(boxes2) // compile error - "type mismatch... you may wish to investigate a wildcard type as `_ <: Box`"
```

If `T` is co-variant then everything compiles.

What's happening here? Why does that one way not compile? I'm guessing it has something to do with the implicit cast, no?

Comment: It's probably something to do with `Set` invariance. Compiler is smart to offer solution that works: `def combine(boxes: Set[_ <: Box[_]])`. But unfortunately I do not understand here everything as well, so I'll wait for a real answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
scala> val boxes2 = Set(Box.build())
boxes2: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Box[_$1]] forSome { type _$1 } = Set(Box$$anon$1@70e0accd)
"""<console>:14: warning: inferred existential type 
scala.collection.immutable.Set[Box[_$1]] forSome { type _$1 }, which
cannot be expressed by wildcards,  should be enabled
by making the implicit value scala.language.existentials visible.
This can be achieved by adding the import clause 'import      
scala.language.existentials'
or by setting the compiler option -language:existentials."""

scala> Box.combine(boxes2)
"""<console>:16: error: type mismatch;
found   : scala.collection.immutable.Set[Box[_$1]] where type _$1
required: Set[Box[_]]"""

scala> val boxes3: Set[Box[_]] = Set(Box.build())

scala> Box.combine(boxes3) // OK
```

The compiler infers the existential type to the outer type, so the result object has a type that doesn't fit `combine`

```
def check[A,B](implicit ev: A =:= B) = true

check[Set[Box[_]], Set[Box[t] forSome { type t }]] // true
check[Set[Box[_]], Set[Box[t]] forSome { type t }] // ERROR
```

as `Set[Box[t] forSome { type t }]` is different from `Set[Box[t]] forSome { type t }`

However, type variance also plays a role here:

```
def f: Box[_] = Box[Int]()   // Box is invariant in its type arg
def g: List[_] = List[Int]() // List is covariant in its type arg

f  // Box[_] = Box()
g  // List[Any] = List() 

Set(f,f)  // ERROR: type mismatch (as Set is invariant)
Set(g,g)  // OK: scala.collection.immutable.Set[List[Any]] = Set(List())

List(f,f) // List[Box[_ >: _$1 with _$1]] forSome { type _$1; type _$1 } = List(Box(), Box())
```

Comment: That's a fine technical explanation, but I'm still left unsatisfied; why is way #1 any different from #3? In both cases I would expect the compiler to do the same "auto casting" interpretation for me. This is maybe less of a technical question and more of a "philosophical" one

Comment: The difference is that, while in (1) and in (2) the compiler knows that the expected type is `List[Box[_]] =:= List[Box[t] forSome { type t }]` (and thus it correctly binds the existential to the inner type), in (3) the compiler has no clues and, by default, it binds the existential to the outer type.

Comment: Are you saying that in #1, the clue for the compiler is the type of `boxes` argument in `combine`? (in #2 it's obviously the explicit typing on the `val`)

Comment: To my understanding, yes.